# nightwatchjs - How to detect hidden html elements?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

There is a form with checkbox and input fields

Checkbox looks(looks custom style) hidden in browser view, hidden option by css (opacity:0 ) [example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_checkbox)

So nightwatchjs couldn't detect checkbox is exist or not

How to solve this scenario ?

```
formFieldsExist:function(){
  return this
             .assert.visible('#name')
             .assert.visible('#yesOrNo')
             .pause(2000)
}
```

1) How to detect hidden elements are exist or not ?

2) If there solution, How can detect checkbox status(true or false) ?

Comment: @Nicktar any problem here?

Comment: Do you have an example html?

Comment: Depends on how it is hidden. What if it is hidden like this example? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_hidden_get

Comment: But we can find things that are "hidden" with `style="visibility: hidden;"`.

Comment: @Jortega Can you write syntax here bro ?

Answer (score 2):

If the hidden element is hidden with a style like `style="visibility: hidden;"` you can try.

nightwatch:

---

```
.useXpath()
.waitForElementVisible("//*[@style='visibility: hidden;']"]',1000)
```

python

---

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@style='visibility: hidden;']")
```

Comment: .assert.attributeEquals('#test', 'data-visibility', 'hidden')  got solution added attribute in checkbox ,  May I ask?  how can i trigger to click this element ?

Comment: @ShibinRagh You can try `.click("//*[@style='visibility: hidden;']")` but I have seen issues with trying to click on hidden elements. Let me know if that works.

Comment: okay I had a updated question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59862018/nightwatchjs-trigger-click-matching-attribute-element